# something wicked happened cant solve as i am behind proxy server

Tags: 12.04, networking

I am getting a lot of something wicked happened resolving `extras.ubuntu.com:http` like errors when trying to install anything or updating using `sudo apt-get` command. I found some solution but they all suggested using automatic proxy detection method. As I am behind a specified server that doesn't work for me.

Can anyone suggest me something?

My internet connection seems to be working fine. My proxy IP is `172.31.100.14`. `ping 172.31.100.14` works fine but `ping www.google.com` show error like `network host unreachable`.

Please help. Thanking you.

Comment: did you set your proxy ip in apt.conf for apt-get and bashrc for ping?

Comment: yup I did set my proxy and authentication in /etc/apt/apt.conf file